# how to add js in custom module layout xml file

Tags: layout

I want to add js in my custom module layout xml file
Below is my code:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addJs"><script>varien/provfvfvfvf.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

I have added js but I wont be able to see this js in my module pages.
Whats the thing which I m missing please let me know

Comment: <reference name="head">
           <action method="addJs"><script>varien/provfvfvfvf.js</script></action></reference> this is my code which I m using

Comment: check the cache and clear it

Comment: where provfvfvfvf.js this file is their in your folder structure

Comment: it should be under js/varien/provfvfvfvf.js then it will work fine

Comment: my file path is /skin/frontend/tm_themes/theme724/js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specify the **Handle**. If you want to add the `js` files for all page use `default` handle. i.e.,

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/provfvfvfvf.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Or else you want to add only one page

```
[router_config_node_name]_[controller_name]_[action_name]
```

[image: router_config_node]

eg:

```
<catalog_product_view>
```

Refer this [Link](http://blog.belvg.com/layout-xml-directives-handles-block-reference-action-remove-update.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use this snippet:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script.js</name></action>
```

**EDIT:**

Add layout update in module's config `app/code/.../Your/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_module>
                <file>your_module.xml</file>
            </your_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Put it in layout update file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/your_module.xml`

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/script.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

I used handle `default` but you can use any other handle, according to your needs, e.g. `yourmodule_controller_action`.

Your js file should be in `skin/frontend/base/default/js/script.js`.

Comment: under which tag you used it?

Comment: `<reference name="head">` You can place your js file in `skin/frontend/base/default/...`