# I'm new to Magento I'm using owl carousel in home page for new products but it does not work?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
       <script>
         var $fz = jQuery.noConflict();        
          $fz(document).ready(function() {
           var owl = $fz('.owl-carousel');
           owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
             nav: true,
            margin: 10,
            responsive: {
               0: {
                items: 1
               },
               600: {
                 items: 3
               },
               960: {
                 items: 5
               },
               1200: {
                 items: 6
               }
             }
           });
           owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
             if (e.deltaY > 0) {
               owl.trigger('next.owl');
             } else {
              owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
             e.preventDefault();
           });
         })
   </script>
```

the error shown when running

> (index):632 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):632)
>       at n (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.B (jquery.min.js:2)
>   (anonymous) @ (index):632
>   n @ jquery.min.js:2
>   fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
>   ready @ jquery.min.js:2
>   B @ jquery.min.js:2

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below tutorial to add owl slider.

http://www.anderswik.se/magento/2015/06/28/Magento-Adding-Owl-Slider.html

Comment: now i'm using magento 1.9.3

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error (is not a function) says you are not loading **owlCarousel** library... double check your Javascript resources loaded in the page

You can download it here https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

And here you have more info about adding a Javascript resource in Magento layout files: [how to add js in custom module layout xml file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78880/how-to-add-js-in-custom-module-layout-xml-file)